# linear regression/ols regression with python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, linear-regression, olsmultiplelinearregression

I want to run multiple linear regression models, and there are 5 independent variables (2 of them are categorical).

Thus, I first applied onehotencoder to change categorical variables into dummies.

These are dependent and independent variables

```
y = df['price']
x = df[['age', 'totalRooms', 'elevator',
        'floorLevel_bottom', 'floorLevel_high', 
        'floorLevel_low',
        'floorLevel_medium','floorLevel_top',
        'buildingType_bungalow', 'buildingType_plate', 
        'buildingType_plate_tower', 'buildingType_tower']]
```

Next, I tried the following two methods, but found that their results are different only for the intercept and categorical variables.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

mlr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
mlr.fit(x, y)

print('Intercept: \n', mlr_in.intercept_)
print("Coefficients:")
list(zip(x, mlr_in.coef_))
```

This gives

Intercept:
35228.96453917408

Coefficients:
[('age', 1046.5347118942063),
('totalRooms', -797.7667275033103),
('elevator', 11940.629576736419),
('floorLevel_bottom', 1011.5929167549165),
('floorLevel_high', 157.60625500592502),
('floorLevel_low', 483.89164772666277),
('floorLevel_medium', 630.9547280568961),
('floorLevel_top', -2284.0455475443687),
('buildingType_bungalow', 31610.88176756009),
('buildingType_plate', -9649.087529585862),
('buildingType_plate_tower', -8813.187607409624),
('buildingType_tower', -13148.606630564624)]

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

x_in = sm.add_constant(x_in)
model = sm.OLS(y, x_in).fit()
print(model.summary())
```

but this gives

---

Intercept                  2.43e+04
age                       1046.5347
totalRooms                -797.7667
elevator                  1.194e+04
floorLevel_bottom         5870.7604
floorLevel_high           5016.7738
floorLevel_low            5343.0592
floorLevel_medium         5490.1223
floorLevel_top            2575.1220
buildingType_bungalow     3.768e+04
buildingType_plate       -3575.1281
buildingType_plate_tower -2739.2282
buildingType_tower       -7074.6472

Now I don't understand the difference between them ;(

Answer (score 0):

Few things to take care of assuming you have done data preprocessing exactly for each iteration. (By the variable names I think there might be something else you might've done)

1. Set the seed to the same number so that results will pick the same random number, to begin with.
2. Avoid dummy variable trtap and use `pd.get_dummies(x, columns=['floorLevel', 'buildingType'], drop_first=True)`